# Drawing a circle with Pyautogui from top to bottom

Tags: python, geometry, mouse, pyautogui

I would like to create a half circle from top to bottom with my mouse, using Pyautogui. Currently I am using a script that works from right to left or left to right. But I can't manage to make the script to work from top to bottom. Here is the current script,

```
import pyautogui
import math

R = 40
(x,y) = pyautogui.size()
(X,Y) = pyautogui.position(580,311)


pyautogui.moveTo(X+R,Y)
pyautogui.mouseDown();
for i in range(180):  
    if i%6==0:
       pyautogui.moveTo(X+R*math.cos(math.radians(i)),Y+R*math.sin(math.radians(i)))
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

So right now it goes to the location, adds the radius then starts drawing the circle. I would like it to add the radius on top and start drawing down. I know how to add the radius on top, but drawing downwards is the struggle. So if anyone can help that would be great!

Thanks,
GetRektOrElse

Comment: Huh, wow. I feel bad that no one answered you yet. I am also wondering something similar. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hello there GetRektOrElse,

I would like to start this answer by apologising for my horrible code styling, I am primarily a mathematician and I am not very familiar with styling.

I have taken a different approach to solving this problem to yourself by using the equation of a circle in cartesian coordinates: `(x ** 2 - a) + (y ** 2 - b) = r ** 2` where point (*a*, *b*) is the centre of the circle and *r* is the radius of the circle. By rearranging this equation you can find a formula for *x* in terms of *y*: `sqrt((r ** 2) - ((y - b) ** 2)) + a`. By iterating through integer values of *y* this equation can be used to find the relevant value for *x* on each pixel row from which you are able to draw you circle.

I believe that this approach is slightly more intuitive than the one which you have used and is more versatile for other transformations which one might want to do in the future.

```
import pyautogui
import math

r = 36
centrex = 2778
centrey = 505

y = centrey - r
x = math.sqrt((r ** 2) - ((y - centrey) ** 2)) + centrex

oldx = x
oldy = y

for i in range(r):
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    x = math.sqrt((r ** 2) - ((y - centrey) ** 2)) + centrex
    pyautogui.dragTo(x, y)
    tempx = centrex - math.sqrt((r ** 2) - ((y - centrey) ** 2))
    tempoldx = centrex - math.sqrt((r ** 2) - ((oldy - centrey) ** 2))
    pyautogui.moveTo(tempoldx, oldy)
    pyautogui.dragTo(tempx, y)
    pyautogui.dragTo(x, y) # comment this line if you want to disable fill

    oldx = x
    oldy = y

    y = y + 1
```

Again I would like to apologise for how disgusting I'm sure this code is however it performs the function that you desire in the way I described above. If you have any questions please feel free to ask and thank you for asking such an interesting question!

Hope you are staying well,

bobbattalion

Answer (score 0):

Change;

```
pyautogui.moveTo(X+R,Y)
```

To;

```
pyautogui.moveTo(X,Y+R)
```

Also if you want it to start top to bottom, use a negative figure for your radius.